# SQLite Where Field Like Text Query

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to run a query on my database in xcode, and it keeps returning 0, even though there are 5 entries. The code to call the database is shown below:

```
-(int)CountWins
{
    int count = 0;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &_db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char* query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wins WHERE (Action LIKE 'Win');";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, query1, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        //Loop through all the returned rows (should be just one)
        while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db) );
    }

    // Finalize and close database.
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    //sqlite3_close(articlesDB);
    }
    [self closeDB];

    return count;
}
```

Basically when the user Wins a game, Win is stored in the action in the database with a timestamp. All i need to know is why my query isnt working, if i do a simple count i get the right number of rows.

Here is my code that inserts the win to the database:

```
-(void) addwin
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];


    NSDate *TimestampVal = [NSDate date];
    NSString *actionVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Win"];
    NSString *sqlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO 'Wins' ('Timestamp','Action') VALUES (?,?);"];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *str = [sqlstr UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, str, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [ [dateFormatter stringFromDate:TimestampVal] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [actionVal UTF8String],-1, NULL);
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE){
        NSAssert(0,@"Error Updating Table.");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

I have also tried to store this query as a string and convert to UTF8String, however that doesnt seem to matter as more simple queries still work.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Cheers

Comment: How do you know there are 8 rows? What other DB methods do you use? Are you sure your code is reaching `sqlite3_column_int`?

Comment: If I change the query to just be "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wins" then it finds 5 rows in the database, using the exact same method just a different query. So i know there are 5 rows, and i know the 5 rows contain the word "Win" in the action column as ive tested my method for inputting the word into the database and its successful. So it really comes down to my query seemingly being poorly syntaxed, yet no matter how i change the quotations or substitute 'LIKE' with '=' i still cant get it to work.... the frustrating thing is i had it working, deleted it and redid it and it stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wins WHERE (Action LIKE 'Win')
```

is actually same as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wins WHERE Action='Win'`.

If your criteria is "contain word win", then

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wins WHERE Action LIKE '%Win%'
```

is what you are looking for!

Comment: Unfortunatly no, Perhaps there is an error somewhere else in my code thats causing this one, any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like my save code to send action to the DB is the issue...it appears to be populating that field with the number 1 instead of wins.

Comment: in fact wins are storing to the Timestamp field... so the real issue was that it was storing to the wrong place.